# Whit it? Different results for same code

Tags: html, css, html-table

It's ok ...:

[image]

but:

[image]

Why it? I'm developing a web site, and it's a trouble, a really trouble. 
The code:

```html
<!-- CSS goes in the document HEAD or added to your external stylesheet -->
<style type="text/css">
table.gridtable {
 font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
 font-size:11px;
 color:#333333;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: #666666;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.gridtable th {
 border-width: 1px;
 padding: 8px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #666666;
 background-color: #dedede;
}
table.gridtable td {
 border-width: 1px;
 padding: 8px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #666666;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
<!-- Table goes in the document BODY -->
<table class="gridtable">
<tr>
 <th>Info Header 1</th><th>Info Header 2</th><th>Info Header 3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Text 1A</td><td>Text 1B</td><td>Text 1C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Text 2A</td><td>Text 2B</td><td>Text 2C</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Why it?

Comment: exactly of what use are those pictures? you don't explain HOW you loaded your page into the browser, or how the local file v.s. http url appears.

Comment: On the second site try pressing `Ctrl`+`0`. You seem to have zoomed out a bit. Normalize the zoom level.

Comment: Yes, this worked. Wait, please...

Comment: Yes, is really it the best reply. I was developing a responsive layout, and the table was all wrong.

Sorry for the useless question. kkkkk

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are more zoomed in on the 1st table than in the 2nd. You can try zooming in on the second, and the bordering should reappear.